# zenstruck_form_bundle (How to use a Custom Repository)

Tags: symfony

I have some difficulties with the zenstruck_form_bundle.
I am looking for an example in which "repo_method" is used.

I'm working in a symfony project (I’m a beginner).

**In my Form Type:**

```
->add('mentions', 'zenstruck_ajax_entity', array(
            'class' => 'AimaFormationBundle:Mention',
            'use_controller'    => true,
            'property' => 'mention',
            'repo_method'    =>  'searchMentionByDomaineDfe',
            'extra_data' => [$idDomaineDfe],
            'label' => '* MENTIONS',
            'multiple' => true,
            'placeholder' => 'La mention (4 lettres min)',
            'required' => true,

             ))
```

**In my Repository Method :**

```
//Recherche des mentions par domainedfe
public function searchMentionByDomaineDfe($idDomaineDfe)
{

     $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m');

     $qb->innerJoin('m.domaineDfe', 'd' , 'WITH', 'd.id = :domdfe');

     $qb->setParameter('domdfe', $idDomaineDfe);

       return  $qb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the official doc: https://github.com/kbond/ZenstruckFormBundle

It's written :

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'zenstruck_ajax_entity', array(
                'class'             => 'AppBundle:MyEntity', // ensure MyEntity::__toString() is defined
                'use_controller'    => true,
                'property'          => 'name', // the entity property to search by
                // 'repo_method'    => 'findActive' // for using a custom repository method
                // 'extra_data'     => array() // for adding extra data in the ajax request (only applicable when using repo_method)
            ))
        ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

*I think it's an exemple...*

**UPDATE:**

The field '`repo_method`' required a string that is the name of a method inside the linked repository. Not a query builder...

Look at the [official doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) to create a custom repository.

Comment: Bonjour et merci pour la réponse. Oui j'avais vu la doc, justement dans cet exemple j'aurai aimé avoir un peu plus de précisions sur le "repo_method" et sur "extra_data".Quand j'essaie d'utiliser une méthode qui se trouve dans mon repository (qui me fait juste l'équivalent d'un (SELECT *) ça ne fonctionne plus. Je continue mes recherches, merci encore.

Comment: @MaillotVictor What is not working ?[you should translate your post in english] Do you have any error message ?

Comment: ok, my error message is : "The data to encrypt cannot be empty".
My code : 
'repo_method'  => function (EntityRepository $er) 
{ return $er->createQueryBuilder('f')->getQuery()->getResult();}

Thanks.

Comment: You give a function instead of a function's name who need to be in the repository, look my update...

Comment: ok, i put the name of my repository method.
Sorry but i don't understand, How i can pass (send) a value to my repository method ?

Comment: If your function inside the repo is call myfunction($param1, $param2) : 'repo_method'=> 'myfunction', 'extra_data' => ['value1', 'value2']

Comment: I put My "form type" and my "repository method" in my first post, did you see something wrong ?
Thanks.